Mahan's derivation of energy current of a free-particle system
On p.25 of the 3rd Ed. analogously to the polarisation operator $\textbf{P}$ for particle currents
$$\textbf{P}=\int\textbf{r}\rho(\textbf{r})d^3r$$
he defines an operator
$$\textbf{R}_E=\frac{1}{2}\int\textbf{r}\mathcal{H}(\textbf{r})+\mathcal{H}(\textbf{r})\textbf{r}d^3r$$
He defines the energy current, $\textbf{j}_E=\partial_t\textbf{R}_E$, then claims that for a free-particle system, the energy current is
$$
\textbf{j}_E=\sum_{\textbf{p}\sigma}\textbf{v}_{\textbf{p}}\epsilon_{\textbf{p}}c_{\textbf{p}\sigma}^\dagger c_{\textbf{p}\sigma}
$$
My question is how does he get to this?  I think since $\partial_t$ doesn't make sense for a free particle system, he's using the commutator relation to get the time evolution, but if you plug
$\psi=a_ke^{ikr}$ into the definition of $\textbf{R}_E$, using $H=\nabla^2$ the first term gives
$$\frac{\hbar^2}{2m}\psi^\dagger \textbf{r}\nabla^2\psi=\frac{\hbar^2}{2m}\psi^\dagger \textbf{r}\nabla^2e^{ikr}=-\frac{\hbar^2k^2}{2m}\textbf{r}\psi^\dagger\psi$$
for the second term, we use the product rule (and reusing an old short-hand he's used previously) to find
$$\frac{\hbar^2}{2m}\psi^\dagger\nabla^2(\textbf{r}\psi)=\frac{\hbar^2}{2m}\left[\psi^\dagger \textbf{r}\nabla^2\psi+2\psi^\dagger(\nabla \textbf{r}\cdot\nabla\psi)\right]=\frac{\hbar^2}{2m}\left[-\textbf{r}\psi^\dagger\psi+2\psi^\dagger\nabla\psi\right]$$
where the only difference is an additional $\frac{i\hbar^2k}{2m}\psi^\dagger\psi$ term.  However, once we carry out the integral terms with $\textbf{r}$ dominate and the integral diverges.  Using the alternative definition of
$$\frac{\partial}{\partial t}\textbf{R}_E=\frac{1}{2}\int\textbf{r}\frac{\partial}{\partial t}\mathcal{H}(\textbf{r})+\frac{\partial}{\partial t}\mathcal{H}(\textbf{r})\textbf{r}d^3r=\textbf{j}_E$$
doesn't seem to change anything either.  Even if we got to a stage where we had something to put into the commutator $\partial_t\textbf{R}_E=i[H,\textbf{R}_E]$ the number operators would commute, meaning the current would be zero.  How does he get the energy current for a free particle system?

I think you lost a factor of 2 in expanding $\nabla^2(r\psi)$. Also $\int xdx=0$, since it is an asymmetric function (under some regularization caveats, which are implied when using plane waves.) $\mathbf{r}$ is a vector, whereas $r=|\mathbf{r}|$ is its magnitude (there might be some confusion between gradient $\nabla r$ and divergence $\nabla \cdot\mathbf{r}$)

@RogerV. you're right there's a factor of two missing that I've now added back in, but that still doesn't change the overall outcome of the argument.  Wouldn't $\int xdx=0$ only work for 1. Cartesian coordinates 2. Integral limits being $a,-a$?  This wouldn't be something that's generally true, especially when we change to spherical coords where $r$ is always positive.  All the $r$s here are $\textbf{r}$, and it's by a quirk that $\nabla\textbf{r}$ acts like the identity, it's not $\nabla\cdot\textbf{r}$.

Integral $\int \mathbf{r}f(r)d^3r$ is going to have the same value regardless of the system of coordinates, in which it is evaluated. what is important here is that this is an integral of a vector function (essentially, three different integrals - one for each component) - not identical with $\int rf(r)d^3r$, which is a single integral of a scalar function. I really think that the problem here is poor handling of vectors.

@RogerV. the question has to do with actually evaluating the integral, I realise Mahan's notation isn't ideal but I've managed to understand what it is.  However, I can't use the same method I used on particle currents on energy currents, hence the question.

It is not about notation, but about the errors (or perhaps inconsistent use of natotation) in your Q., where you without justification replace vector (in bold font) by its magnitude. Once you fix this, the integral the you claim as divergent will vanish due to parity, as per my first comment. Then a more serious discussion would be possible.

@RogerV. I've changed it, but the same issues still stand 1.  Vanishing due to parity is only true if your volume is symmetrically centred at the origin (e.g. I don't think this would hold for a system with a hexagonal lattice, since either way you rotate it you would either have two output paths on one side or an "even" Y shape) 2.  If the terms with $\textbf{r}$ vanish then that gets rid of the $\epsilon_k$ term which is in Mahan's solution.

For a hexagonal lattice you will have different dispersion relation and specific  integration limits (typically over the Brillouin zone). Can you derive particle and energy current in standard one-particle QM, using continuation and equation and SE? It does give $v_\mathbf{p}\epsilon_\mathbf{p}$ for a plane wave (provided that we have appropriate BC, so that we can do integration by parts and assume that the integral over the boundary vanishes.)

@RogerV. just to clarify, when you say "continuation and equation" do you mean the continuity equation (in the form $\nabla\cdot\textbf{j}=\partial_tE$ for energy)?  I've managed to do particle current using Mahan's method (here:  https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/820476/259935)

@RogerV. also in one particle QM isn't the particle current density usually defined (as the real part of the momentum)?  I think in this question I'm trying to figure out the form of the density current $\textbf{j}$, not starting from $\textbf{j}$ and solving for the current

@RogerV. I'm also thinking through the energy current in one particle QM, but isn't the plane wave usually considered a steady state solution?  If it's losing energy then surely it cannot be steady state?  Unless I'm not plugging it into the free particle Hamiltonian?

@RogerV. I think I've found a way analogous to the derivation of probability current, but it requires treating the Hamiltonian differently depending (i.e. using $\nabla\cdot(\psi^\nabla\psi)=\psi^\nabla^2\psi+(\nabla\psi^*)\cdot(\nabla\psi)$ for one term and $H\psi=E\psi$ for another).  It has worked out, but I don't think it brings me any closer on Mahan's derivation.

I recommend starting with $\partial_t |\psi|^2 = \partial_t\psi^\psi + \psi^\partial_t\psi=...$, using time-dependent Schrödinger equation and reducing it to the continuity equation $\partial_t\rho + \nabla\cdot\mathbf{j}=0$. I am not sure all QM textbooks derive current this way, but this is done in Landau&Livshitz QM, if I am not mistaken. You could then derive energy current following similar steps.

@RogerV. can you reopen my question so I can type up an answer

@RogerV. I've just submitted my answer, could you take a look and see if it's correct?

TLDR:  $\textbf{r}\mathcal{H}$ is $\textbf{r}\psi^* H\psi$.
In more detail, this is really several questions in a trench coat.  First of all,
Q: What does the energy current actually represent?
If we think about the particle current, we define the sources/sinks in a said volume as the change in mass, i.e. the continuity equation $\nabla\cdot\textbf{j}+\dot{\rho}(t)=0$.  The question now becomes, how to implement this for energy?  We could take the time derivative of the Hamiltonian $\dot{H}$, but operators represents measurements.  If we want to find a continuity equation for energy, we would need the actual measured value of energy.  As such, it makes sense to start with the expected value of energy
$$\nabla\cdot\textbf{j}+\partial_t\int\psi^*H\psi d^3r=0$$
Now let us look at what this would give for a travelling wave wave-function.  This corresponds to the free particle Hamiltonian
$$H=\frac{-\hbar^2}{2m}\nabla^2$$
As such, by Leibnitz' rule we can move the $\partial_t$ into the integral, which gives
$$\dot{\psi}^*H\psi+\psi^*H\dot{\psi}$$
from the Schroedinger equation
$$i\hbar\dot{\psi}=H\psi$$
we can substitute this in to get
$$\left(\frac{1}{-i\hbar}H\psi^*\right)(H\psi)+\psi^*H\left(\frac{1}{i\hbar}H\psi\right)$$
Now, we can use the eigenfunction property of $\psi,\psi^*$ to rewrite $H\psi=E\psi$ and $\psi^*H=E\psi^*$.  Now, this brings us the next question
Q:  Why are we treating the Hamiltonian differently based on whether it came from the Schroedinger equation or not?
The answer to this is because we are trying to find the energy current, which we know is related by $\nabla\cdot\textbf{j}$.  As such, we'd expect to be able to express our RHS as an overall divergence.  Since $\nabla^2u$ for a scalar function $u$ is defined as $\nabla\cdot(\nabla u)$, any higher order $\nabla$ will likely not be needed.  To simplify the equation, we've then chosen to get rid of two orders of $\nabla$ by using the eigenfunction property.  This then leaves us the $\nabla^2$ in the Hamiltonian, which we can guess can be split using
$$\begin{split}
\nabla\cdot(\psi^*\nabla\psi)&=\psi^*\nabla^2\psi+(\nabla\psi^*)\cdot(\nabla\psi)\\
\nabla\cdot(\psi\nabla\psi*)&=\psi\nabla^2\psi^*+(\nabla\psi^*)\cdot(\nabla\psi)
\end{split}$$
which gives
$$\nabla\cdot{\textbf{j}}=\frac{E}{i\hbar}\cdot\frac{\hbar^2}{2m}[\nabla\cdot(\psi^*\nabla\psi)-\nabla\cdot(\psi\nabla\psi^*)]$$
Since $\hat{p}=-i\hbar\nabla$, we can rewrite this as
$$\frac{E}{2m}[\psi^*\hat{p}\psi+\psi\hat{p}\psi^*]$$
which is simply the real part of the expected value of the momentum.  Thus, this is simply
$$\epsilon_k\textbf{v}_k$$
from which we can follow (How do you get from the polarisation operator to particle current?) to reproduce the energy current from the $\int\textbf{r}\mathcal{H}d^3r$ form.  This leads to our last question
Q:  Does it make sense to look at the energy current for a plane-wave, given that it exists over all space?
Yes!  The wavefunction gives a probability distribution, but the particle collapses to a single point after measurement.  We use the wavefunction because that is where information such as particle momentum or energy is described.  Although the wavefunction is spread out over all space, the particle itself has a defined momentum, so when we take the integral over a surface it gives the probability that the particle carries the energy out of that surface.
